# Securing publishing page layouts

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, publishing-page

I'm having some issues finding a good pattern to make some publishing page layouts secured.

The page layouts are built like this

The page layout

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Externwebb.PageLayouts.MyPage, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PortalWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Code behind

```
namespace Externwebb.PageLayouts
{
    public class MyPage : Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Some more info

- The site is public and have anonymous access enabled
- Visitors can login to the site using a custom membership provider (Claims)
- The site uses managed navigation, *can I implement session requirement for a certain node and/or all descendants*
- Is there some secure version of the `PublishingLayoutPage` class

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by secured? Are you talking about content visible to only authenticated users?

Comment: @PirateEric That is correct, only to authenticated users

Answer (score 0):

In your page layout, you'll want to utilize [SPSecurityTrimmedControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol(v=office.15).aspx). These allow you to build up content regions and place security restrictions on them as to who can see it.

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID=”SPSecurityTrimmedControl1″
  PermissionsString=”BrowseDirectories” runat=”server”>
    <PublishingSiteAction:SiteActionMenu runat=”server” />
    <wssuc:Welcome id=”explitLogout” runat=”server” />
    <PublishingWebControls:AuthoringContainer ID=”authoringcontrols”
    runat=”server”>
        <PublishingConsole:Console runat=”server” />
    </PublishingWebControls:AuthoringContainer>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

I've used these in a variety of scenarios to show content on the page only for admins and targeting.